# C# how to insert null value for foreign key into SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have one table Documentation that has foreign keys to 3 other tables. This table, Documentation, should contain documents for different subjects (glass, aircraft and project). I didn't wan't to create 3 tables (table for documents for glass, another table for aircraft documents etc) so I created just one table that will have a reference(foreign keys) to other tables (Glass, Aircraft and Project tables). First of all, I'm not sure if this is a good solution...

Anyway, problem is the following: I want to insert document that refers to glass. This means that foreign keys for Aircraft and Project will be null. Database columns accept null values.
If I try to insert null values for those foreign keys (AircraftFK and ProjectFK) it does not allow me to do that. It's asking me to insert appropriate value for foreign key that already exists as primary key in tabel Aircraft and Project.

These foreign keys (AircraftfK and ProjectFK) HAVE TO BE NULL because the document that I'm inserting has nothing to do with aircraft and project.

I'm programming in c# and using Sql Server 2008.

How can I solve this?

Thank you all

Here are some more info:

this is my sql command:

```
komanda = new SqlCommand("insert into Documentation (GlassFK, FaiFK, ProjectOrderFK, OrderNumberFK, DocPath, DocName, DocSize, DocType, DocumentFile) values (@GlassFK, @FaiFK, @ProjectOrderFK, @OrderNumberFK, @DocPath, @DocName, @DocSize, @DocType, @DocumentFile)", konekcija);

        for (int i = 0; i < listaDokumenata.Count; i++)
        {
            komanda.Parameters.Clear();
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlassFK", listaDokumenata[i].GlassFK);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaiFK", listaDokumenata[i].FaiFK);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectOrderFK", listaDokumenata[i].ProjectOrderFK);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumberFK", listaDokumenata[i].OrderNumberFK);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocPath", listaDokumenata[i].PutanjaFajla);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName", listaDokumenata[i].ImeFajla);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocSize", listaDokumenata[i].VelicinaFajla);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", listaDokumenata[i].Ekstenzija);
            komanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentFile", listaDokumenata[i].Fajl);
```

and here is c# code for creating document object:

```
Document sf = new Document();
                    sf.PutanjaFajla = putanjaFajla;
                    sf.ImeFajla = imeFajla;
                    sf.Ekstenzija = ekstenzija;
                    sf.VelicinaFajla = velicinaFajla;
                    sf.Fajl = wordFile;
                    sf.FaiFK = 5;
                    sf.GlassFK = 0;
                    sf.ProjectFK = null;
                    sf.ProjectOrderFK = 0;
```

This means that this document will refer to Glass. All other foreign keys has to be 0 or null (depends on a attribute type in sql)

So, here is the error that I get:

The parameterized query '(@GlassFK int,@FaiFK int,@ProjectOrderFK int,@OrderNumberFK nvar' expects the parameter '@OrderNumberFK', which was not supplied.

OrderNumberID is the primary key of table Project. Its foreign keys is OrderNumberFK

Comment: There is no problem in having a nullable FK column. What is *asking you to insert values*? Please show your code, describe what errors are you getting.

Comment: @MichalKlouda I have edited question with more info and some code

Comment: `sf.GlassFK = 0;` I guess this zero is your problem. It is passed to your INSERT query.. And I bet there is no Glass entity with ID 0. Also the error complains about missing parameter `@OrderNumberFK`.

Comment: It is true that I have no ID=0, but what value should I insert instead of it, because I don't need any reference to other table? Practically, I need to "ignore" that FK in database.
As for order number, I have the same problem with all FK-s. This is just one sample.

Comment: I don't understand, are you aware of the fact that `0` and `NULL` are two completely different values? Inserting `NULL` will work if your column allows NULLs.

Comment: ID is int type in the database. Because of that I have gave that ID=0. If I can give him value NULL, how can I say that in C# code?
int aircraftDK = null? I know that this is not possible and I don't know how to forward NULL to database from c#. I'm new to sql and even to c#.

Comment: Omit the column in INSERT command or try setting parameter's value to `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Thank you very much! I've solved it with DBNull.Value. If no value was selected in the form then I've setted the parameter to DBNull